# How do I use windows authentication with roles with Hot Towel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, breeze, hottowel

I can spin up a standard asp.net mvc 4 intranet project and decorate the controller or methods with things like:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize(Roles = "MyApp Users")]
```

I have tested it and it will work perfectly (since my domain account is a member of the "MyApp Users" in Active Directory)

However my problem/question is how do I get the same type of behavior for a ["Hot Towel"](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/hottowel-template) application?  I try decorating my breeze controller, HotTowel Controller, or any method with the same attribute and I can never authenticate... what gives?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a role provider setup?  Check the IPrincipal and see if your are signed in also.

Comment: I'm using the default role provider for asp.net mvc... nothing custom.  And yes, if I check the IPrincipal it shows me as logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  I hope this is of use to others.

First you must set the WindowsProvider as your roleManager like so:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider"
   enabled="true"
   cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="WindowsProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then you will be able to check the roles for the user [using Roles.IsUserInRole()], and more specifically to this question **use the authorize attribute**.  The only thing is that you will have to include the domain in the authorize attribute, like so:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize(Roles = "YourDomain\\MyApp Users")]
```

And now everything works as you would expect.